# Как прочитать ответ от сервера

Tags: c#

Отправляю запрос на API сайта, подобного вида :

```
 var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip");
        using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(gzipStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8")))
                    {
                       return reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

ответ должен прийти такого вида :

```
"date": {
        "UTC": "2016-02-01 11:00:00",
        "unix": 1454324400,
        "local": "2016-02-01 14:00:00",
        "time_zone_offset": 180
    }
```

Как правильно его вычитать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это ответ в виде JSON текста, его надо расшифровать, для дальнейшей работы, вот некоторые методы — https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.helpers.json(v=vs.111).aspx